# Block domain masking from nginx

Tags: url, nginx, server, mask, unicorn

Some bad person is masking my website with his domain www.baddomain.com. I would like to block it somehow from my `nginx` config file if that is possible.

I tried to see from "baddomain.com" source code if he is using URL frame, but can't find one. Also domain extensions are being duplicated on every page.

I have filled Copyright Claim with his domain issuer but that could be long process or useless.

I own "original.com" but he owns "baddomain.com". I don't want google to think there is duplicate content with my site.

How could I block masking url from Ninx? I use DigitalOcean droplet, Ruby on Rails. Unicorn and Nginx for server!

Comment: How exactly is he masking your website ? Don't you own the domain `www.baddomain.com` ? Or he owns the domain and simply mirrors your content ? Or someone has brute-forced your password for domain registrator and has pointed your own domain to his web server ? If you are a legitimate user of DigitalOcean, then simply fire a case to their support staff and explain the problem. Surely they will provide some help to you.

Comment: The problem is that he owns "baddomain.com" and is using it to mirror my site "example.com". I don't want google to think there is duplicate content, but I can't turn off others people domain account. I tried to see if it is using URL frame but I can't see it from source code at "baddomain.com" @IVOGELOV

Comment: May be this will help - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/29879, and also this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/541140/5962802

Answer (score 0):

This post answered it, its actually my own question but in ServerFault https://serverfault.com/questions/796674/block-masking-url-from-nginx/